# Is there actually a "railroad to nowhere" on the border between Ukraine and Russia?

Tags: historical-context, ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad, serhiy-zhadan

In *Voroshilovgrad*, Herman had the following discussion with some smugglers about some rail on the border of Ukraine and Russia:

> "There's a railroad here?" I asked.
> "Well, yeah," Mr. One-Eye answered.
> "Where does it go?"
> "Nowhere."
> "What do you mean 'nowhere'? It must go somewhere."
> "Nope. It doesn't. They were building it here in case of war. But they started building it from the center, laying track in either direction. Well, they never wound up connecting this line to anything at either end. So they just stopped."

Is there actually rail like this in Ukraine?